# Can't start mysql service

Tags: mysql, percona

I don't know why but yesterday mysql stops working. I have Ubuntu 14.04.

I did this:

```
service mysql start
```

And got following errors:

> df: '/var/lib/mysql/.': Permission denied
>   * /etc/init.d/mysql: ERROR:
>   The partition with /var/lib/mysql is too full!

Then I run same command with `sudo` and got this message:

> - Starting MySQL (Percona Server) database server mysqld

And it keeps starting but can not be started, because `sudo service mysql status` gave me this:

> - MySQL (Percona Server) is stopped.

I did some research and people says that it cant be caused by wrong permissions for my.conf file, but they are correct:

> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3,5K февр. 20  2014 /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Comment: try it with `sudo` i.e. `sudo service mysql start`

Comment: I tried this and wrote about it in my question.

Comment: The permission problem is said about /var/lib/mysql, check that

Comment: It is drwx------ 24 mysql mysql 4096 нояб. 25 00:09 mysql

Comment: /dev/sda7       65146596     25537096 36277520           42% /

Comment: Well, finaly I just reinstalled percona.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the mysql conf and increase the amount of data it can store .. It maybe that for some random reason u may have hit the storage limit set for mysql in the config file.

Comment: What variable should I change?

Comment: See for me on windows with apache MySQL its all in on conf file where is says max store limit as a var Ubuntu may have similar file but if u getting permission errors and partition full errors it could be an update that has changed the permissions or as it say the space is full ..

Comment: first, tail -f /var/log/mysql/error.log to check the log info. I also meet similar thing, my error info is => InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M, InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool;

second, I edit /etc/mysql/my.cnf, to add innodb_buffer_pool_size with small value as 'innodb_buffer_pool_size = 64M';

finally, service mysql start works.